# compatibility of Thom classes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Let $\mathcal{H}^{\bullet}$ be a generalized (Eilenberg--Steenrod) cohomology theory and $p:E\rightarrow X$ be a rank $r$ real vector bundle over a finite CW-complex, we know that a Thom class $\lambda_E\in \tilde{\mathcal{H}}^{r}(\text{Th}(E))$ with respect to $\mathcal{H}^{\bullet}$ corresponds to an $\mathcal{H}^{\bullet}$-orientation on $E$.

- For singular cohomology, the orientation is the usual one.
- For real topological K-theory, the orientation is equivalent to a $\textsf{spin}$ structure.
- For topological K-theory, the orientation is equivalent to a $\textsf{spin}^c$ structure.

The Thom class is generally not unique and different Thom classes will generate different Gysin maps, so even the composition rule for Gysin map requres us to make a choice for Thom classes. Now assume more that $\mathcal{H}^{\bullet}$ is also mutiplicative with a cup product $\cup$, we consider the following two properties :

- composition rule for Gysin maps
- $\lambda_{E\times F}=\text{Th}(q)^*\lambda_E\cup\text{Th}(p)^*\lambda_F$ with $q:E\times F\rightarrow E$ and $q:E\times F\rightarrow F$
- $\lambda_{f^*E}=\text{Th}(g)^*\lambda_E$ with $f:Y\rightarrow X$ and $g:f^*E\rightarrow E$

where vector bundles $E,F$ are $\mathcal{H}^{\bullet}$-orientatble.

> Do we have a choice to make all the properties above hold simultaneously？

Comment: How do you define a Thom class for a non-orientable VB?

Comment: @Z.M We do not require VB to be orientable, we need  the $\mathcal{H}$-orientability.